# Which is the first hook executed on Serverless?

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless-architecture

There is a predefined hook how to default on Serverless? I want to know if the framework execute any hook before and with are these ordered by execution. Looking at the official docs, I can't found any explanation of this in details.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are also plugins:

- [serverless-scriptable-plugin](https://github.com/weixu365/serverless-scriptable-plugin)
- [serverless-plugin-scripts](https://github.com/mvila/serverless-plugin-scripts)

where you may trigger scripts depends on the lifecycle events from the serverless framework.

[The most complete serverless lifecycle events list](https://gist.github.com/HyperBrain/50d38027a8f57778d5b0f135d80ea406).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. The question was made to understand if exist something defined from the framework without use third-party implementations.

Comment: I would not consider plugins as third-party implementations. There were requests of implementing some of the features for serverless but they were rejected and closed with comments like - this feature is covered by plugin `some awesome plugin`, thus it will not be implemented.